# I am getting following error while importing database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using wprdpress and my website is running well. I have exported database via phpmyadmin. when i am trying to import for other server I am getting this error. Am i making any mistake while importing or I will have to make changes in database??

Not able to import database...getting this error as attached...[error while importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9MY3.jpg)

Comment: Paste the code error here. Even in the picture I still can't read it. [images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Install and use updraftplus plugin on both sites to export and import

Answer (score 0):

Try to Increase phpMyAdmin upload / import size.

Go to php.ini and find the following lines

upload_max_filesize = 20M

post_max_size = 20M